# Jetpack Compose & Navigation: Does routes within a nested NavGraph have to be globally unique?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-navigation, jetpack-compose-navigation

I am facing an issue. I have a navigation graph that nests two (sub)graphs with the same inner routes. A minimum example would look like this:

```kotlin
navigation(route = "a", startDestination = "b") {
    composable("b") { Button(onClick = { navController.navigate("c") }) { Text("ab") } }
    composable("c") { Button(onClick = { navController.navigate("b") }) { Text("ac") } }
}
navigation(route = "x", startDestination = "b") {
    composable("b") { Button(onClick = { navController.navigate("c") }) { Text("xb") } }
    composable("c") { Button(onClick = { navController.navigate("b") }) { Text("xc") } }
}
```

When I navigate through the first nested graph (home -> "a" -> "b" -> "c"), everything works fine.

When I navigate through the second nested graph, it breaks (home -> "x" -> "b" <del>-> "c"</del> ). I mean, when I click the button on the "x/b" screen, that is supposed to navigate to "c", it throws the following error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: eu.dateio.dateiosdkmutliplatform.android.demo, PID: 5052
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No destination with ID -443542924 is on the NavController's back stack. The current destination is Destination(0xe5901276) route=c
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.getBackStackEntry(NavController.kt:2209)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.addEntryToBackStack(NavController.kt:1918)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.addEntryToBackStack$default(NavController.kt:1813)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController$navigate$4.invoke(NavController.kt:1721)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController$navigate$4.invoke(NavController.kt:1719)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController$NavControllerNavigatorState.push(NavController.kt:287)
        at androidx.navigation.NavigatorState.pushWithTransition(NavigatorState.kt:88)
        at androidx.navigation.compose.ComposeNavigator.navigate(ComposeNavigator.kt:50)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigateInternal(NavController.kt:260)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.kt:1719)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.kt:1662)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.kt:1984)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate$default(NavController.kt:1979)
        at eu.dateio.dateiosdkmutliplatform.android.demo.ui.DemoActivityKt$DemoScaffold$2$1$3$1$1.invoke(DemoActivity.kt:137)
        at eu.dateio.dateiosdkmutliplatform.android.demo.ui.DemoActivityKt$DemoScaffold$2$1$3$1$1.invoke(DemoActivity.kt:137)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.ClickableKt$clickable$4$gesture$1$2.invoke-k-4lQ0M(Clickable.kt:153)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.ClickableKt$clickable$4$gesture$1$2.invoke(Clickable.kt:142)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.gestures.TapGestureDetectorKt$detectTapAndPress$2$1$1.invokeSuspend(TapGestureDetector.kt:222)
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTaskKt.resume(DispatchedTask.kt:178)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTaskKt.dispatch(DispatchedTask.kt:166)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuationImpl.dispatchResume(CancellableContinuationImpl.kt:397)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuationImpl.resumeImpl(CancellableContinuationImpl.kt:431)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuationImpl.resumeImpl$default(CancellableContinuationImpl.kt:420)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuationImpl.resumeWith(CancellableContinuationImpl.kt:328)
        at androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.SuspendingPointerInputFilter$PointerEventHandlerCoroutine.offerPointerEvent(SuspendingPointerInputFilter.kt:563)
        at androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.SuspendingPointerInputFilter.dispatchPointerEvent(SuspendingPointerInputFilter.kt:455)
        at androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.SuspendingPointerInputFilter.onPointerEvent-H0pRuoY(SuspendingPointerInputFilter.kt:468)
        at androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.Node.dispatchMainEventPass(HitPathTracker.kt:310)
        at androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.Node.dispatchMainEventPass(HitPathTracker.kt:297)
        at androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.Node.dispatchMainEventPass(HitPathTracker.kt:297)
        at androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.NodeParent.dispatchMainEventPass(HitPathTracker.kt:179)
        at androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.HitPathTracker.dispatchChanges(HitPathTracker.kt:98)
        at androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.PointerInputEventProcessor.process-BIzXfog(PointerInputEventProcessor.kt:97)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.sendMotionEvent-8iAsVTc(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:1280)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.handleMotionEvent-8iAsVTc(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:1230)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.dispatchTouchEvent(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:1169)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.ja
```

Does it mean that the routes within the nested graphs have to be globally unique? Or is it a bug in the navigation library?

Comment: I have the same question.. Have you found the answer? It does seem the routes have to be globally unique..

Comment: @DikenMhrz, no, I haven't yet :-(

Answer (score 1):

As per the [Navigation Compose documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation#create-navhost):

> Route is a String that defines the path to your composable. You can think of it as an implicit deep link that leads to a specific destination. **Each destination should have a unique route.**

So each route must be globally unique.